# place div on top of a iframe to prevent click registering on iframe

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float, css-position

Observe this photo:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5nkE.png)

This is an attempt to put a "click box" on top of an Iframe which has an embeded youtube video.
The reason, I want the youtube video thumbnail to load, but I do not want the video to play when clicked. I want another action to take place. Hence the click box and the event listener on the click box in the code which I will show below.

html:

```
<div class="row mt-5 mb-5" id="upcomingvideosrow">
    <div *ngFor="let video of livevideolibraryitems; let i = index" class="col-xl-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-5 pb-3">
      <iframe *ngIf="video.is_youtube_link"  [src]="video.youtube_link"
              frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <h5 style="display: inline-block" class="text-center mb-5">{{video.title}}</h5>
        </div>
        <div (click)="playselectedvideo(i)" class="col-12 clickbox">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

the div with the css class `clickbox` is the click box that is intended to go over the `iframe`

now the click box is there, I have a green border around it. However you do not see it in the screen shot I uploaded, because it is far below. And the `iframe` dimensions are not the square I am trying to make.

check out the css:

```
iframe{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}



#videoplayercolumn {
  height: 100%;
}

.clickbox{
  border: solid 1px green;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 30vh;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0vh;


}

@media only screen and (min-width: 300px){

  #videoplayerrow {
    height: 270px;
  }

  .marginshim{
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px){

  #videoplayerrow {
    height: 400px;
  }

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px){

  #videoplayerrow {
    height: 500px;
  }

}
```

now I am using positioning relative on the `clickbox`, but i feel that is messing everything up.

Is there a better way? Wanted to ask you guys before I just nuke the whole thing and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Here was the fix!

```
<div class="row mt-5 mb-5" id="upcomingvideosrow">
    <div *ngFor="let video of livevideolibraryitems; let i = index" class="col-xl-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
      <div class="clickbox pb-4" (click)="playselectedvideo(i)">
        <iframe *ngIf="video.is_youtube_link" class="videochoice"  [src]="video.youtube_link"
                frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <h5 style="display: inline-block" class="text-center">{{video.title}}</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

iframe{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.videochoice{
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}



#videoplayercolumn {
  height: 100%;
}

.clickbox{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
```

notice the `clickbox` div, and the `pointer-events: none` on the `.videochoice` class